# Why I am only getting one document using geofirestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I am trying to query the nearest documenst to the user location using `geofirestore`, my code fetch 1 document only, and as you see in the code I set the radius to 100km, and I set the location of the document from the same location.

**This is the document I am querying it**
[image: document number 1]
**And this is the other document with the same radius**
[image: document number 2]

I tried to print the `snapshot` result in a map and it's only print 1 document

**here I send the document id to build the `query` into `recyclerView`**

```
Map<String,Object> stringIntegerMap=new HashMap<>();
private void getNearestEstate(){
    GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFirestore.queryAtLocation(new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude), 100);
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryDataEventListener(new GeoQueryDataEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDocumentEntered(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, GeoPoint geoPoint) {
           stringIntegerMap=documentSnapshot.getData();

            Query query=propertyRef.whereEqualTo("mID",Integer.parseInt(documentSnapshot.getId()));
           dataFetch(query,R.id.discoverRV);

            //here how i tried to print the result to see how many documents i got
            for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : stringIntegerMap.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                String value = entry.getValue().toString();
                Toast.makeText(mContext,key+" "+value,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

**And here i build the query and send it to `recyclerview adapter`**

```
private void dataFetch(Query query,int rvView){
      FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Property> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Property>()
        .setQuery(query, Property.class)
        .build();

mAdapter = new DiscoverAdapter(options);
RecyclerView recyclerView = root.findViewById(rvView);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mAdapter.startListening();
}
```

**here the result of the query**
[image]

Comment: Did you try to restart the router?

Comment: Are you sure you have more than 1 location in 100km radius?

Comment: the longitude and latitude in each document is  my current location

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `com.github.imperiumlabs:GeoFirestore-Android`, right?

As of version v1.5.0, there is a discrepancy between the code and the documentation.  The documentation states that `queryAtLocation` uses **kilometers**:

```
// creates a new query around [37.7832, -122.4056] with a radius of 0.6 kilometers
val geoQuery = geoFirestore.queryAtLocation(GeoPoint(37.7832, -122.4056), 0.6)
```

However, the code converts from **meters** to latitude:

```
fun distanceToLatitudeDegrees(distance: Double) = distance / Constants.METERS_PER_DEGREE_LATITUDE
```

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android/issues/37) on Github.

**Passing meters to the queryAtLocation should solve the problem.**